# Is there any Texts in Hinduism that mentions the existence of different universes(multiverse)?

Tags: scripture, symbolism, creation, science, universe

Modern Science is now reaching the conclusion that multiverse,i.e many universes existing in parallel with each other,is possible thanks to various fields such as String Theory and Quantum Physics.

However, is it possible that in Hinduism it has already been proven that parallel universes exist?

Comment: Well, yes. Krishna divided himself into two parts. One part is Krishna, and other is Virat. In each body pore of Viraat Krishna dwells and each body pore of Viraat is a separate Universe

Comment: Multiverse is just a hypothetical concept, which is not worth discussing according to many scientists. A multistorey building may have many floors, but they are still part of the same building. Similarly all multiple universes can be considered part of single universe. Having said this, in Hinduism & other disciplines, it's believed multiple planes of existence. It may or may not correlate to multiverse theory.